# Can we add SLD parsers for WMS Capability?

Tags: parsing, wms, sld

Currently, the ol/format/WMSCapabilites only parses the mandatory tags of the Capability.Request.
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v8.2.0/src/ol/format/WMSCapabilities.js#L205
I need to be able to read the sld:GetLegendGraphic Request tag.
My question has a few parts:

1. Is there a way to initialise the ol.format.WMSCapabilities to allow it to read SLD formatted tags?
2. If not, is there a reason why? (Never got to it or prefer not to add the SLD format?)
3. Could I provide a patch to add that funtionnality?

I tried to read the response from a GetCapabilities that include a GetLegendGraphic in the Request. The ol.format.WMSCapabilities did not return that option in the Requests.